# Avd not opening sometimes

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse and creating some small applications. When I run my avd, its getting opened sometimes and  sometimes its is not at all giving me any error but closing. I am unable to solve.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine? The emulator sometimes is very slow to respond depending on your computer specs.

Comment: yes.. I have done it several times, even though there isn;t any change in the functionality and it is giving me an error "You were in middle of something .... "

Comment: You should try the recommendations here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes have this same problem, and there are always a few steps I use to get it working again:

- Open the Task Manager and kill the adb.exe process
- Close Eclipse and reopen it
- Open your AVD manager from Eclipse
- Check the settings of the avd you want to launch and lower it's ram by 50MB (or more if you gave it a lot of RAM to start with).

For some reason it doesn't always start when the desired ram use is larger then an X percentage of my total RAM. When I lower this starting amount of ram it always boots up again.